# Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/dag_1_V5.py] cannot import name opentype on airflow

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

Anyone got any experience of the following error on airflow / know what may be causing it?

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/Sql_beast_V5.py] cannot import name opentype
```

I have airflow running on docker on Google compute engine vm, it was working fine before and have been using it for some time. The error came when I made some changes to my docker file and pulled the updated image onto my vm. I've tried rolling back to old docker image but still getting the same issues.

Here is my Docker Make file:

```
FROM sstumgdocker/docker-airflow-mongotools

USER root

RUN apt-get update -yqq
RUN apt-get install -yqq python-pip 
RUN apt-get install -yqq python-dev
RUN apt-get install -yqq default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -yqq postgresql-9.5 
RUN apt-get install -yqq libpq-dev
RUN apt-get install -yqq lzop


RUN pip install apache-airflow[celery,postgres,hive,hdfs,jdbc]==1.9.0 --upgrade
RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN pip install pandas_gbq
RUN pip install slackclient
RUN pip install Flask-OAuthlib

USER airflow
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please show your dag

Comment: the dag isn't the issue as it is working fine on another instance of airflow

Comment: I think it may be something to do with my Docker container as I added an additional package (lzop), however when I remove lzop from make file and start again it still gives the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now resolved the issue, it was indeed caused by an issue with the Docker Make file.

It seems that removing `apt-get install` for `postgresql-9.5` & `libpq-dev` resolved the issue.

See updated  Docker Make file below:

```
FROM sstumgdocker/docker-airflow-mongotools

USER root

RUN apt-get update -yqq
RUN apt-get install -yqq python-pip 
RUN apt-get install -yqq python-dev
RUN apt-get install -yqq default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -yqq lzop


RUN pip install apache-airflow[celery,postgres,hive,hdfs,jdbc]==1.9.0 --upgrade
RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN pip install pandas_gbq
RUN pip install slackclient
RUN pip install Flask-OAuthlib

USER airflow
```